# How to use PgSearch with different localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg-search

I'm implementing PgSearch to rails application. I have to do multisearching between some models and every model has his own translation in separate db table.

For example:
I have an article, so I also have a **article_translation** table, which has column **locale** (ru, en, de). So, for example if current default locale setted to **:en** and when I call **article.article_translation** I get only **en** translation (i did it with has_one association with scope)

So, right now I have a problem with the PgSearch gem. I'm doing multisearch between this translation tables, but I need to specify which language should be used as dictionary and which results should be show depending on dictionary.

If I have a default locale **":ru"** and trying to search something, I should only get a **"ru"** translations results.

Can I implement this functionality with this gem or should I use something else?

Comment: Can you please show your code? At a guess you could just do this by defining a `pg_search_scope` that takes *two* parameters, and calling something like `Article.search_by_name(params[:name], current_user.locale)`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library, but nothing described above seems beyond what's described in the [readme](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search#dynamic-search-scopes).

Comment: @TomLord take a look at gem closer please, I'm using multisearch, and I can't pass any options to it (while multisearching). Am I missed something?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the problem; I'm not going to invest the time trying to create such an example for myself.

Comment: I also don't understand why you are using a *different database table* for each translation; couldn't that be simplified massively via a single `translations` table?